# Show subpages of current page, but subpages of parent page, if the current page has no subpages

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a pagetree like this:

```
home
  foo
    foobar
    foobaz
  bar
    barbar
contact
```

I want to show a navigation menu, that contains all subpages of the current page. I'm achieving this with this `TypoScript`:

```
subNav = HMENU
subNav {
    entryLevel = -1

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul id="submenu">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        }
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li id="active">|</li>
        }
    }
}
```

**But:** When the current page has no subpages, then the subpages of the parent page should be shown.

Examples:

- I'm at page `home`: The menu should show links to the pages `foo` and `bar`.
- I'm at `foo`: `foobar`and `foobaz` should be shown.
- I'm at `foobar`: **Here also `foobar` and `foobaz` should be shown instead of an empty menu.**

Typo3 version is 7.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve it. I had to set `entryLevel` of the `HMENU` to `-1` if the current page has subpages. The `-1` means: Start with che child pages of the current page. If the page has no subpages, the `entryLevel` has to be set to `-2`. That means: Start with the children of the parent page.

`entryLevel` has a `override` property:

```
lib.subMenu = HMENU
lib.subMenu {

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul id="submenu">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        }
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        }
    }

    // -1 = current page
    entryLevel = -1

    // Set entry level to -2 (this is the parent page), if the current page has
    // no subpages.
    entryLevel.override = -2
    entryLevel.override.if {
        negate = 1
        isTrue.numRows {
            table = pages
            where = pid=this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. I love Typoscript cause everything is possible if you see any property has stdWrap properties!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. At the moment I only see a solution with using the stdWrap-properties of entryLevel. So you could make a `entryLevel.stdWrap.cObject = CONTENT` and then perform a select query on pages pidInRootline = current (default?). In the `renderObj` of CONTENT you just return the entryLevel in case subpages are found and if not, the entryLevel of the next highest level.

Like this it should be possible but I hope that anyone has a better solution.

Comment: Thank you. I could solve it with `entry.override`. I first tried to generate a value `-1` or `-2` based on the existence of subpages. This value has been in a `COA`, but I could not set the `entryLevel` to the value of this `COA`. Then I found a solution with `entryLevel.override`.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I wanted to mention that sometimes it‘s an option to think such problems "from front end".

E.g. if there are subpages with *hide in menu* set or other conditions that include or exclude pages from menu you‘ll get an empty menu unless you reproduce that in your `entrylevel.override`. This can be avoided by using something like

```
lib.subMenu = HMENU
lib.subMenu {
    entrylevel = -1
    1 = TMENU
    # ...
    ifEmpty.cObject = HMENU
    ifEmpty.cObject {
        entrylevel = -2
        1 = TMENU
        # ...
    }
}
```

This way you don‘t need to bother *why* your current page‘s menu is empty, the fact it is suffices. Can get a bit fiddly when it comes to wraps, though…

Comment: Thank you for that addition. I can ignore this in this specific project--I think :)

Comment: You‘re welcome! As I said, this is not a solution to beat‘em all :-)